# If a $p \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$ accepts an operator on an unspecified vector space $V$, what does it do with it?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If a polynomial, $p \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$, accepts an operator on an unspecified vector space $V$, what does it do with it?

for example, take some $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, what does $p(T)$ do, exactly? is $p(T)$ also an operator on V? If so, how does it act on some $\vec{v} \in V$?

I am trying to prove that a certain polynomial, $p(\lambda)$, $ \lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, is an eigenvalue of that same polynomial applied to some unspecified $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$. I am given that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Unfortunately, my textbook has one confusing example of what it means for a polynomial to be applied to an operator. More examples or explanation would be great. I am not looking for a proof, just information to help me prove it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just treat multiplication as function composition.

If your polynomial is $p(X) = aX^2 + bX + c = aX^2 + bX + cX^0$ then for a linear operator $T:V \to V$ the corresponding polynomial is $p(T) =a(T \circ T) + bT  + cI$ where $I=T^0$ is the identity map.

Applied to an input, you will have $(p(T))(v) =aT(T(v)) + bT(v)  + cv$

Comment: so then, a polynomial applied to an operator is also an operator on the same vector space?

Comment: Thats right, you can think of the polynomial map $p$ as being a map of linear transformations to linear transformations.